# how to connect and insert the ASP with sql server 2005?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

Am using the following program for insert the value in sql server 2005 using ASP.but i dont know how to connect the asp with sql server 2005.but i use the following program i got the error.how can i solve this?what is the other way to connect the aspo and sql server 2005 for insert the record?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
     dim con, sql_insert, data_source="XEONSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=abcd; User Id=abcd;password=abcd;";   
     sql_insert = "Insert into register values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')";
     set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
     con.Open data_source;
     con.Execute sql_insert;
     con.Close;
     set conn = Nothing;
%>

<form action="Default.aspx" method="post">
Your name:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this an asp.net question or an asp-classic question?

Comment: Must be ASP.NET as ASP would freak out over the use of ;

Can you please remove the ASP-Classic tag as it's misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm personally using this set of functions in my DBHelper class

You just need to paste the connection string instead of: "SettingsHelper.getConnection()"

```
public class DBHelper
{
    public static void runQuery(string lc_cmd, LogHelper logger)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SettingsHelper.getConnection());
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(lc_cmd, cn);
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            if (logger != null)
            {
                logger.Write(e.ToString());
                logger.Write(lc_cmd);
            }
            else
            {
                throw (e);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            cn.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void runQuery(string lc_cmd)
    {
        runQuery(lc_cmd, null);
    }




    public static SqlDataReader GetSqlDataReader(string Query, int SQLTimeOutSeconds)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SettingsHelper.getConnection());
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = SQLTimeOutSeconds;
        return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }


    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string Query, LogHelper logger)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SettingsHelper.getConnection());
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, conn);
            DataSet s = new DataSet();
            a.Fill(s);
            return s.Tables[0];

        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            if (logger != null)
            {
                logger.Write(e.ToString());
                logger.Write(Query);
            }
            else
            {
                throw (e);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Dispose();
        }

        return null;
    }


    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string Query)
    {
        return GetDataTable(Query, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: i just insert the record in sql server data base.Is i use the whole class DBHelper in my asp?

Comment: you can add DBHelper.cs in your app_code directory and then just call 

`DBHelper.runQuery("Insert into register values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')");`
But be aware about potential vulnerability by SQL injection in your application

Comment: Note that this code is in c# and would only apply to an asp.net application (aspx pages), your question is also tagged with classic asp, if you need a classic asp example, please let us know - your connection string & it's declaration is the problem though at first glance – would be helpful if we knew what error you were getting.